# Unbinding specific scroll events within jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a small jQuery plugin that creates sticky sidebars and I've tried to create a "destroy" method which removes the stickyness. It works fine however I'm using it on multiple elements on the page (sticky sidebar within accordions) and when I destroy one, it removes the scroll events for all the others.

```
    $parent.find('.js-opps-aside').stickAside();



    var thisScroll = $(window).on('scroll', enqStick);

    ...

    $(window).off('scroll', thisScroll);
```

I thought that was how to unbind specific scroll events, however, as I said it removed all the event handlers. I just want it to remove the scroll event for this specific element it was called upon, and leave the other elements with their scroll events intact.

Comment: Could you give some context to the three lines of code? When do they run? What is `enqStick`? What is `thisScroll`? Not sure I follow.

Comment: Ya, you have to provide MCVE, your question is missing context. You are binding scroll event to window level, so how do you target specific scrolled element? We need to see your logic part regarding it

Comment: Sorry, I thought the above code was enough. And from the answers it seemed just about so :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use $().off(), the second parameter is a reference to the event handler, and you try to off with `thisScroll` but it is a jQuery collection.
You should use this :

```
$(window).off('scroll', enqStick);
```

You can use another solution that is think is better, just suffit the event name

```
$parent.find('.js-opps-aside').stickAside();

$(window).on('scroll.myCustomScroll', enqStick);
...
$(window).off('scroll.myCustomScroll');
```

`$().off` with only one parameter will off all event callbacks associated with the event, in our case it will of all `scroll.myCustomScroll`

Answer (score 1):

According to jQuery stacking logic thisScroll is $(window).
What you would like to do is:

```
// Binding a handler
$(window).on('scroll', enqStick);

// removing handler by bound function handler
$(window).off('scroll', enqStick);
```